# How to move an element to top by -100% of the height of the element?

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I have an element and I assigned `top: -100%` to the element. I need `top: -100%` to be translated to `top: -{height-of-the-element}`. But what I am getting is `top: -{height-of-another-element-wrapping-it}`.

Here is some code (not full code, as it's very complex) to explain the HTML and CSS:

```
<nav>
    <section>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <ul class="i-want-to-use-top-here"></ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

```
nav {
    height: 60px;
}

.i-want-to-use-top-here {
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
}
```

Why it's happening like this? How can I get -100% of the height of the element to use in `top`?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with [`transform: translate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) since you don't seem to be concerned with keeping it in normal flow.  That way, you don't need to worry about changing the height if the elements contents ever change:

```
.i-want-to-use-top-here {
  background: rgba(175,175,175, .5);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -100%);    
}
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/fuBr9/

Answer (score 0):

add position: relative; to nav and try again.

Answer (score 0):

`top` always assigns position relative to the parent element. However, if you're manually setting the height, as you appear to be based on your css, why not manually set top to the same value?

```
.i-want-to-use-top-here {
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -200px;
}
```

Then, if/when you change the `height` programmatically, just change the `top` value at the same time.

Comment: Good question. In real, there is no height for `.i-want-to-use-top-here`. It will vary according to number of elements in it. I have given height 200px here, to explain why, in my case, `top: -100%` is translating to `top: -60px` instead of `top: -200` or something else.